# Google Calendar API, Events returns a 400 badRequest every time

Tags: json, events, google-calendar-api, bad-request

I am posting to the following url:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/axxxa@mydomain.com/events?conferenceDataVersion=1&access_token=mytoken
```

The JSON object that I post is

```
{
    "summary": " some subject",
    "location": "Online",
    "description": "some description",
    "sendUpdates": "none",
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2020-10-21T09:00:00:00",
        "timeZone": "Asia\/Kolkata"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2020-10-21T10:00:00:00",
        "timeZone": "Asia\/Kolkata"
    },
    "conferenceData": {
        "createRequest": {
            "conferenceSolutionKey": {
                "type": "hangoutsMeet"
            },
            "requestId": "1232"
        }
    },
    "attendees": [
        {
            "email": "one@mydomain.com"
        },
        {
            "email": "two@mydomain.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the error message that I get.

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "badRequest",
                "message": "Bad Request"
            }
        ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Bad Request"
    }
}
```

My search so far revealed that the issue could be with my JSON object, but I can't see an error anywhere. It is not an issue with token, have checked. Checked camelCase names, removed some non-mandatory elements, but the error remains the same. Only when I take out end time, does it say missing end time. Else the error is always constant.. and as given above. Have spent a few hours on this already, and figured may be someone else may be able to spot the issue.

Comment: send the access token as an authorization header its a bearer token.   What language are you using to send this request?

Comment: @DaImTo I am using php curl to send the request. Will try as an authorisation header and let you know. Funny, that the same code works in another area. Have an issue only here.

Comment: in the future please include your code so someone could test it.   This should have included the curl statement it would have meant i could have tested it for you directly instead of just looking at it and making guesses.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. It was right in front.. dateTime has to be

```
 "dateTime": "2020-10-21T09:00:00",
```

instead of

```
 "dateTime": "2020-10-21T09:00:00:00",
```

Did not notice the extra :00 at the end. Thanks for trying to help.